# Jquery not skipping php if condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

The Jquery language is a bit like french to me so apologies if this is one of my less smarter questions but consider this:

**PAGE1.php**

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
some stuff
</form>
```

**Page2.php**

```
 //form values posted 2 form2
    <?php
     session_start();
    //Check if user is logged in
    //if user not logged in display modalbox
    if(!isset($_SESSION['members']) || !isset($_SESSION['FBID'])){
        ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $.fancybox(
            '<h2>Hi!</h2><p>This is where login form will be</p>',
            {
                    'autoDimensions'    : false,
                'width'                 : 350,
                'height'                : 'auto',
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            }
        );
    });
   </script>
    <?php
    }//if not logged in
    ?>  
    <?php
    else{
    //Do stuff with logged on user with  values posted from page1.php
    }
```

**My Problem**

*Regardless if user is logged in or not the login modal box gets displayed.*

According to my logic if user is logged in the modal box should not be displayed and the code should go to the else part

Comment: so, when a user is logged in, _SESSION contains both `members` and `FBID` ?

Comment: one suggestion  write `session_start();` at top of your second page after `<?php`

Comment: Try `var_dump($_SESSION);` and see what it contains

Comment: @JaromandaX No a member can be logged in either via site registration `memeber` or  via FB `FBID` hench  I check for both

Comment: the modal is showing if one or both of those vars aren't set. It's likely that you forgot to call session_start(); in your code, so no variables in $_SESSION will be set at all.

Comment: shouldn't that || be a && ? i.e. only one of these needs to be set for the user to be logged in, so the modal will show unless the user is logged in via both methods.

Comment: @Rob I feel like a real idiot now if you want to add that comment to an answer I will accept

Comment: Jaromandas should be the one you accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['members']) || !isset($_SESSION['FBID'])){
```

wants to be

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['members']) && !isset($_SESSION['FBID'])){
```

so the modal only shows if the user isn't logged in by either method

Answer (score 2):

based on your answer

> No a member can be logged in either via site registration memeber or via FB FBID hench I check for both

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['members']) || !isset($_SESSION['FBID'])){
```

means if EITHER one of those is not set, you'll get the login

you want

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['members']) && !isset($_SESSION['FBID'])){
```

or

```
if(!(isset($_SESSION['members']) || isset($_SESSION['FBID']))){
```

you are doing if not logged in via A or not logged in via B ... they can't be logged in both ways

first answer ... if not logged in via A AND not logged in via B

second answer if not (logged in via A or logged in via B)

boolean logic with "not" can trip you up

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this line

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['members']) || !isset($_SESSION['FBID'])){
```

to

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['members']) && !isset($_SESSION['FBID'])){
```

The reason is that you're currently checking if either of the session variables are not set... which means, if one is and the other isn't, it'll return false.

You want to see if *both* aren't set - so you need to use `&&`.

Comment: @vogomatix Not quite mate... And you're missing a close parenthesis after `['FBID'`

Answer (score 0):

This is no problem with jQuery. You forgot to start you session.

Add `session_start()` in your `Page2.php`.

Comment: Can you show us your login code? And maybe add the full code of `page2.php`, so we can see if something went wrong there.